# Hide and Show Div on change in Select Box Item

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="group">
  <label class="require" for="Roles">Roles</label>
  <select id="Roles" class="roles" name="Roles">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Professor</option>
    <option value="2">Student</option>
    <option value="3">Director</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="group hide" id="cv">
  // Something
</div>
```

I would like to add the class "show" to div with id="cv" when the option Professor is selected and switch back to class hide when one of the other options is selected.

How can I do this? I am using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#Roles").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "1") {
        $("#cv").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#cv").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    }
});
```